# Select array objects without numbers

Tags: regex, powershell

I have an array imported via `Get-Content` with IPS, FQDNs and host names. I am able to extract the IP addresses out of said list due to another users function, however trying to modify said function now `ExtractRawHost` I can't get just the parts without numbers. Now I think this is due to the first function having Matches and Address in the regex however I don't understand what's going on there.

```
function ExtractValidIPAddress($String) {
    $IPregex='(?<Address>((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))'
    if ($String -Match $IPregex) {$Matches.Address}
}

function ExtractRawHost($String) {
    $Hostregex='[^a-zA-Z]'
    if ($String -Match $Hostregex) {$String}
}

$raw = Get-Content C:\automation\Monitor\Servers\RawList.txt
$ips = @()
$rawHost = @()
foreach ($server in $raw) {
    $rawHost += ExtractRawHost($server)
    $ips += ExtractValidIPAddress($server)
}
```

Example of what is in rawList is.

```
server1
10.10.10.10
server2.atmydomain.com
```

Comment: Can you please update your post to include an example of the text you are trying to match?  I don't know powershell, but from what I can tell, your current regex is trying to match anything that is not a letter.  Which would only give you numbers, punctuation, symbols, spaces, etc.

Comment: @Quixrick Sure updated, I found a workaround but if you have a better way feel free to let us all know.

Comment: Why not just `Import-CSV .\YourFile.txt -Delimiter ' ' -Header 'ServerName1','IP','ServerName2'` then you can avoid all the regex matching.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Would that work if the list is in no specific order and is about 600 items long? How would it know what to map what to?

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into your question. If you found a solution yourself: post it as an answer of your own.

Comment: Sorry about that.. Its not a great answer... so I hope someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Ah, formatting is kind of important here. Previously you had the three lines combined and separated by a space. The updated format will not be conducive to using `Import-CSV`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that function `ExtractRawHost()` should match lines such as `server1`, but not lines with IP addresses (e.g., `10.10.10.10`) or FQDNs (e.g., `server2.atmydomain.com`).

However, its regex, `[^a-zA-Z]`, matches any line that contains *at least 1 char. that is not a letter*, which is true of *all* your sample input lines (`[...]` defines a *set* / *ranges* of characters that match a *single* character; `^` *right after `[`* negates that set / the ranges; since the `[...]` is neither anchored (such as with `^` and `$` *outside* `[...]`) nor quantified (such as with `+`), *any* character in the input may match).

Assuming that it is sufficient to identify the raw hostname by matching lines that do *not* contain a period, `'^[^.]+$'` would do.

Alternatively, if you want to identify raw hostnames more strictly by lines that start with an (ASCII) letter, followed by any mix of (ASCII) letters and digits, use `'^[a-z][a-z\d]+$'` - note that you needn't specify uppercase letters separately, because PowerShell's regex matching is case-insensitive by default.

Here's a simplified implementation based on the latter, using a `switch` statement rather than separate functions; also, IP addresses are simply identified by starting with 1 - 3 digits followed by a period (`^\d\{1,3}\.`).

```
# Sample input lines.
$lines = @(
    'server1'
    '10.10.10.10'
    'server2.atmydomain.com'
)

$rawHosts = @()
$ips = @()
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    switch -regex ($line) {
        '^[a-z][a-z\d]+$' { $rawHosts += $line; break }
        '^\d{1,3}\.'      { $ips += $line; break }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am all for using `Switch`, but it might be a little overkill here. Probably simpler to do a simple `If($Line -match <regex for IP address>){[array]$ip += $line}Else{[array]$rawHost += $line}`. I'd avoid specifying IPs by starting with a digit, since a server could in theory also start with a digit.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: Thanks for the digit tip: I had mistakenly assumed that hostnames mustn't start with a digit - fixed. As for `switch` vs. `if`: while `if` certainly works, I prefer `switch` here, not least because it generalizes more easily to more cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to capture the `server2.atmydomain.com`, you can use something like this:

```
Function ExtractRawHost($String){
    $Hostregex='.*?(?![\d.]+)(?=\w+\.\w+\.\w+)(?<RawHost>[^\s]+)'
    If ($String -Match $Hostregex) {$Matches.RawHost}
}
```

Not sure if powershell allows for lookaheads and negative lookaheads, but here's what I'm doing:

- `.*?` - Looking for anything that may or may not be before the part we want to match.
- `(?![\d.]+)` - Negative lookahead `(?! ... )` to say that strings consisting of only digits `\d` and dots `.` should not be matched.  This will exclude the IP addresses.
- `(?=\w+\.\w+\.\w+)` - This is a lookahead `(?= ... )` to find a word character `\w`, at least one time `+`, followed by a dot `.`.  I repeat this again a second time and a third time, without the dot after it.  This just tells it that the format has to match `something.something.something`.
- `(?<RawHost>[^\s]+)` - Now, we are naming our capture group `(?<RawHost> ... )`.  It will capture anything that is not a whitespace character `[^\s]`, but is at least one character `+`.

Give that a go and let me know if it's working for you.  As I mentioned in the comments above, I do not know the powershell syntax, so I just copied the rest from the previous example that seems to work.

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/kz6Q1O/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
           Function ExtractValidIPAddress($String){
                $IPregex=‘(?<Address>((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))’
                If ($String -Match $IPregex) {$Matches.Address}
            }

            Function ExtractRawHost($String){
                 $Hostregex=‘(?<Address>((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))’
                 If ($String -notmatch $Hostregex) {$server}
            }


            $place = 0
            $raw = Get-Content C:\automation\Monitor\Servers\RawList.txt
            $ips = @()
            $rawHost = @()
            foreach($server in $raw) {

                $rawHost += ExtractRawHost($server)
                $ips += ExtractValidIPAddress($server)

            }
```